# SQL select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these tables currently:

```
assignments(assignment_id, module_id, year, semester, title, number, weighting)
module(module_id, code, name, crn, course_title)
usermodule(usermodule_id, user_id, module_id)
users(user_id, title, first_name, last_name)
```

I was wondering if anyone could give me guidance on how to get the lecturer name, based on the module_id?

So far I've come up with:

```
SELECT `first_name` FROM `users` WHERE `assignments.module_id` = '$module_id';
```

I think I may have to do some form of JOIN query...

Comment: where is the lecturer? Is it the user_id from UserModule table? If it's a many-to-many relationship, how do you know which one is the lecturer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query

```
SELECT u.first_name FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN usermodule um ON um.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE um.module_id = '$module_id';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try below sql

```
SELECT `first_name` FROM `users` WHERE user_id =  (select user_id from usermodule where module_id = '$module_id' limit 1))
```

Comment: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

That's the error I get when I try it in phpMyAdmin SQL :/

Comment: try this : SELECT `first_name` FROM `users` WHERE user_id =  (select user_id from usermodule where module_id = '$module_id' limit 1)

Comment: I don't want to limit the result to 1. I would like to aquire all of the assignments written by a lecturer.

Comment: This query does not limit to one record that is just for subquery limitation.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT  `first_name` 
FROM    `users` u INNER JOIN
        `usermodule` um ON u.user_id = um.user_id
WHERE   `um.module_id` = '$module_id';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rhis:

```
    SELECT `first_name` FROM
   `users` INNER JOIN `usermodule` ON `users.user_id`=`usermodule.user_id` 
    INNER JOIN `assignments` ON `usermodule.module_id` =`assignments.module_id`   
    WHERE `assignments.module_id` = '$module_id';
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'assignments.module_id' in 'where clause'
 
But the column exists in that table. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

I see poor structuring of your database.

You do not necessarily need a table `usermodule` to create relationships between the other tables.

If there is a relationship between a user and a module.

make use of a foreign key.

You could have a `user_id` in the module to link a user to a given module, then have `'module_id'` in assignment to link a given assignment to a module, that way in the end, the user, module and assignment are related.

It will then be easy to use JOIN or simple select query

Comment: I thought I would need a usermodule table because there is a many to many relationship between the users and their modules?